Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/up' undefined
I got this code
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{chessboard}     
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}
\hypersetup{citecolor=Green}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\lhead{Chess Puzzles}
\begin{center}
\large   \underline{Puzzles}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Puzzle \href{https://lichess.org/training/PMdLu}{\#PMdLu},
Rating: 2002.\\
Themes: 
\begin{center}
\vspace{-15pt}\chessboard[setfen=8/1p3p2/1Pp1kP1P/2Pp2K1/p3b3/P2rR3/8/8 w - - 1 45]
\end{center}
\textbf{Solution.} h7, Rxe3, h8=Q.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

And this warning:
Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/up' undefined

So I added
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

But it did not help. I also searched the web for answers and one StackExchange site suggested to add
\usepackage{lmodern}

to the preamble. Well... it did not help. Neither did adding
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

I usually ignore warnings. But thit one bothers me... any hints?

It is only a warning. You can make the substitution silent as David does, but this is not (from your point of view) something amiss. There is the question of why chessboard looks for a shape which is not standard (to say the least), so the content of the warning is unusual. But it is not especially unusual for shapes or whatever to require substitution and, unless explicitly told otherwise, LaTeX will always 'warn' you about that.

@rallg That's not the problem. There is no up shape. Not in any standard font, anyway. There is n, but not up. (\upshape uses n.)

You could simplify your example to
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}     


\begin{document}

\chessboard[setfen=8/1p3p2/1Pp1kP1P/2Pp2K1/p3b3/P2rR3/8/8 w - - 1 45]

\end{document}

which makes
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/up' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 8.

something in chessboard is expecting the non standard name up for the normal upright shape rather than n  The simplest thing is to define up here to silently substitute for n
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}     
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmss}{m}{up}
       {<->ssub*cmss/m/n}{}

\begin{document}

\chessboard[setfen=8/1p3p2/1Pp1kP1P/2Pp2K1/p3b3/P2rR3/8/8 w - - 1 45]

\end{document}

You could do a similar substitution for whichever font family you use.

Great. Sadly I cannot use lmodern anymore. Actually I would like to use mlmodern to get a fat lmodern. Can this be achieved?

just add \usepackage{mlmodern} then the same substition of up to n @calculatormathematical

Sorry, but what to do if you get Font shape "OT1/phv/m/up" undefined ?

@calculatormathematical that's exactly the same, substitute it to phv/m/n
